# Creating a class object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to create an object of a class, but it doesn't seem to work, I can't help but think I am looking at this from a JAVA perspective:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PortChecks PortCheckObject = new PortChecks();

        }

private void testCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PortCheckObject.MyMethod();
        }
```

I can error when using the PortCheckObject to call my method MyMethod

(PortChecks is the class name)

Comment: That wouldn't work in Java either.

Comment: Your `PortCheckObject` is a local variable in the contructor of Form1 that you cannot access from `testCheck_Click`. This would be the same even in Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because it's outside of the scope of `testCheck_Click`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PortChecks PortCheckObject = new PortChecks();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void testCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PortCheckObject.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, should have seen thar,, ^ ^

Answer (score 3):

`PortChecks PortCheckObject` in `Form1` constructor is a local variable.
Put its declaration as a private field in `Form1` class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PortChecks PortCheckObject = new PortChecks();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void testCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PortCheckObject.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@James,

You need a class property with the name 'PortCheckObject' and can be possible to access in other parts of the class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PortChecks PortCheckObject;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PortCheckObject = new PortChecks();
    }

    private void testCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PortCheckObject.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a general scope issue, not a Java v.s. C# issue (as your code wouldn't work in Java either).  PortCheckObject is in Form1()'s scope, not testCheck_Click's scope.  Try the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PortChecks PortCheckObject;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PortCheckObject = new PortChecks();

    }

private void testCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PortCheckObject.MyMethod();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of a scope problem. You do not have scope in your testCheck_Click method. Make the following change and it should work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PortChecks MyPortCheck {get; set;}

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyPortCheck = new PortChecks();
    }

    private void testCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPortCheck .MyMethod();
    }

...
}
```